# C# Dynamic Classes with DRY

Tags: c#, dynamic

So, I'm creating a REST API with EF and C# and end up having a lot of classes with exactly the same structure.  The only thing that's different between them is the naming and variables.  I'm having a hard time trying to understand what I need to be looking for to dynamically create a class depending on which API endpoint gets called.

Here are two example classes:

```
public class SiteExtendedAttributesBooleanContext : DbContext<ExtendedAttributeBoolean>
{
    public SiteExtendedAttributesBooleanContext(string nameOrConnectionString, string schemaName)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString, schemaName)
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this is used for unit testing only b/c a parameterless constructor is needed to create a proxy
    /// </summary>
    protected SiteExtendedAttributesBooleanContext() : base("A fake connection string", "FAKESCHEMA")
    {
        // ReSharper disable once VirtualMemberCallInConstructor
        OnModelCreating(new DbModelBuilder());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExtendedAttributesBooleanMap("SITE_EXT_BOOLEAN"));

        var conv = new AttributeToTableAnnotationConvention<TenantAwareAttribute, string>(
            TenantAwareAttribute.TenantAnnotation, (type, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnName);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(conv);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class AssetExtendedAttributesBooleanContext : DbContext<ExtendedAttributeBoolean>
{
    public AssetExtendedAttributesBooleanContext(string nameOrConnectionString, string schemaName) 
        : base(nameOrConnectionString, schemaName)
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this is used for unit testing only b/c a parameterless constructor is needed to create a proxy
    /// </summary>
    protected AssetExtendedAttributesBooleanContext() : base("A fake connection string", "FAKESCHEMA")
    {
        // ReSharper disable once VirtualMemberCallInConstructor
        OnModelCreating(new DbModelBuilder());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExtendedAttributesBooleanMap("ASSETS_EXT_BOOLEAN"));

        var conv = new AttributeToTableAnnotationConvention<TenantAwareAttribute, string>(
            TenantAwareAttribute.TenantAnnotation, (type, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnName);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(conv);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have a single class and create another one using different Naming and different values in the strings?  I've been Googling things like Dynamic types, ExpandoObject, TypeBuilder, etc. but I'm not sure what matches my needs.

I already know the structure of all my classes, just don't want to have to sets of 10 classes for every different API endpoint I'm creating.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want to do. Yo speak about a REST Api with EF -"depending on which API endpoint gets called"- but what I see is that you are implementing multiple DbContexts with has nothing to do with REST Apis, can you clarify a little more what you are trying to implement?

Comment: Can I make those two classes into just one class and somehow call them during runtime using specific names and values?

Comment: Will inheriting from a generic DbContext<T> works for you?

Comment: Seems like it would depend on how you're using it. I don't see any reason to dynamically create classes when you could easily pass the `"...EXT_BOOLEAN"` values in.

Comment: @Arnel we actually have a custom DbContext but I took off the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an enum like this:
`enum ContextType { Site, Asset, OtherOne }`

and add a parameter to the constructor:
`public ExtendedAttributesBooleanContext(string nameOrConnectionString, string schemaName, ContextType context)`

So you can pass `ContextType.Site`, `ContextType.Asset` or the other one when instantiating. Now you can determine the string from what was passed in the constructor.

Create a private string field `typeString`. In the constructor, assign either "ASSETS" or "SITE" based on the passed argument (`typeString = context == ContextType.Site ? "SITE" : "ASSETS";`), and then in `OnModelCreating` just replace the string literal with `typeString`.

Comment: This is close.  I don't have a problem with the string values.  I'm more curious how I could create a class called `DynamicExtendedAttributesBooleanContext` and have it build one for `AssetExtendedAttributesBooleanContext` and `SiteExtendedAttributesBooleanContext` and so on for 15 other objects.  I need to include these contexts in other classes that are going to use the specific context.

Comment: @BenWilliams I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying you want to have 17 classes that only differ with just one string variable?
Something tells me you are looking for Factory design pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx
http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1219951/Implementing-Csharp-Factory-Pattern-with-Dynamic-C

Comment: By the way, you should remove the irrelevant code from the question. It makes too much clutter

Answer (score 0):

Figured out part of my question for another area of my application.  I essentially can do this:

```
private Dictionary<string, dynamic> DynamicContexts => new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
    {
        {"DOC_DOCUMENTS_EXT_BOOLEAN", DocumentExtendedAttributesBooleanContext},
        {"DOC_DOCUMENTS_EXT_STRING", DocumentExtendedAttributesTextContext}
        {"AST_ASSETS_EXT_BOOLEAN", AssetExtendedAttributesBooleanContext},
        {"AST_ASSETS_EXT_STRING", AssetExtendedAttributesTextContext}
    }
```

and to get the right context, I call them as:

```
DynamicContexts[validEaTable]
```

I still am working on finding solutions for the original classes I posted in here.  Might need to do some kind of abstract class or inheritence.  Not sure yet.